# Splash screen library in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a splash screen library in jQuery. The splash screen will display until the website has completed loading all the images. I just wanted to review if there are any improvements.

Here is the code:

````js
(function (window, document, undefined) {
    $.SplashScreen = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend(
            {
                id: "splashscreen",
                desktop: true,
                mobile: true,
                forceLoader: false,
                queryParameter: "loader",
                progressCount: false,
                progressCountId: "status",
                progressBar: false,
                progressBarId: "progress",
                fadeEffect: true,
                timeToFade: 1000, // In milliseconds (eg: 1000 = 1sec)
                timeOut: 2000, // In milliseconds (eg: 2000 = 2sec)
            },
            options
        );

        function id(v) {
            return document.getElementById(v);
        }

        function loadSplashScreen() {
            var qstring = getQueryStringVars(window.location.href);

            if (settings.forceLoader) {
                settings.forceLoader =
                    qstring[settings.queryParameter] != null && qstring[settings.queryParameter] != "" && (qstring[settings.queryParameter] == "true" || qstring[settings.queryParameter] == "t" || qstring[settings.queryParameter] == "1")
                        ? true
                        : false;
            }

            if (settings.mobile) {
                settings.mobile = $.DetectMobile() != null ? $.DetectMobile() : false;
            }

            if (settings.mobile || settings.desktop || settings.forceLoader) {
                var overly = id(settings.id),
                    img = document.images,
                    progCount = id(settings.progressCountId),
                    progBar = id(settings.progressBarId),
                    c = 0;
                totalImages = img.length;

                function imgLoaded() {
                    c += 1;

                    if (settings.progressBar) {
                        var percentage = (((100 / totalImages) * c) << 0) + "%";
                        progBar.style.width = percentage;
                    }

                    if (settings.progressCount) {
                        progCount.innerHTML = "Loading " + percentage;
                    }

                    if (c === totalImages) {
                        var element = document.getElementById(settings.id);
                        element.IntervalPageCompleted = setTimeout(function () {
                            return pageLoadCompleted();
                        }, settings.timeOut);
                    }
                }

                function pageLoadCompleted() {
                    if (settings.fadeEffect) fade(settings.id);
                    else {
                        overly.style.opacity = 0;
                        overly.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
                    var tImg = new Image();
                    tImg.onload = imgLoaded;
                    tImg.onerror = imgLoaded;
                    tImg.src = img[i].src;
                }
            } else {
                id(settings.id).style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function getQueryStringVars(url) {
            var vars = [],
                hash;
            var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
                hash = hashes[i].split("=");
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }

        function animateFade(lastTick, eid) {
            var curTick = new Date().getTime();
            var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

            var element = document.getElementById(eid);

            if (element.FadeTimeLeft <= elapsedTicks) {
                element.style.opacity = element.FadeState == 1 ? "1" : "0";
                element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + (element.FadeState == 1 ? "100" : "0") + ")";
                element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? 2 : -2;
                return;
            }

            element.FadeTimeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
            var newOpVal = element.FadeTimeLeft / settings.timeToFade;
            if (element.FadeState == 1) newOpVal = 1 - newOpVal;

            element.style.opacity = newOpVal;
            element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + newOpVal * 100 + ")";

            setTimeout(function () {
                animateFade(curTick, eid);
            }, 33);
        }

        function fade(eid) {
            var element = document.getElementById(eid);

            if (element.FadeState == null) {
                if (element.style.opacity == null || element.style.opacity == "" || element.style.opacity == "1") element.FadeState = 2;
                else element.FadeState = -2;
            }

            if (element.FadeState == 1 || element.FadeState == -1) {
                element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? -1 : 1;
                element.FadeTimeLeft = settings.timeToFade - element.FadeTimeLeft;
            } else {
                element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 2 ? -1 : 1;
                element.FadeTimeLeft = settings.timeToFade;
                setTimeout(animateFade(new Date().getTime(), eid), 33);
            }
        }

        try {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadSplashScreen(), false);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex.message);
        }
    };

    // Detecting mobile phone
    $.DetectMobile = function () {
        var isMobile = {
            Android: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
            },
            BlackBerry: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
            },
            iOS: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
            },
            Opera: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
            },
            Windows: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
            },
            any: function () {
                return isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows();
            },
        };

        return isMobile.any();
    };
})(window, document);
```
````